# HTML form loading the old form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a small problem with my form. I'm using **[Halo Template](https://themeforest.net/item/halo-material-design-mobile-template/14981441)**

The problem that I'm having is I have one simple form, where a user can upload their own picture

```
<form action="userpics/upload.php" name="picUpload" id="picUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="visibility:hidden" onchange="submitform()">
    <input type="submit" value="" name="submitme" id="submitme" style="visibility:hidden">
</form>
```

So, when I go to post a topic and somebody is going to upload a Picture on the new topic instead of loading

```
 <form action="listingPics/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="visibility:hidden" onchange="submitform()">
    <input type="submit" value="" name="submitme" id="submitme" style="visibility:hidden">
</form>
```

It loads the first one... I'm very dumb-founded as to why it is; or how I can fix it.

Comment: Just clarifying, is your issue the fact that when someone uploads a picture on the new topic it changes their own picture instead of posting the picture to  the topic?

Comment: Yes, but it can go the other direction too, instead of uploading a picture of yourself, it'll try to upload a picture to a topic instead. The form action is what changes. Instead of listingPics it'll go to userpics, and vice versa.